# Create an attribute without value using cheerio

Tags: angular, cheerio

Is it possible to create an attribute to a DOM element using cheerio without setting a value for it?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

I am trying to manipulate angular template HTML files using cheerio. So my use case is something like

```
<input placeholder="My input" name="input"/>
```

to

```
<input directiveInput placeholder="My input" name="input"/>
```

This is what I have so far

```
        const $ = cheerio.load(htmlContent,  {
          xmlMode: true
        });
        $('input').attr('directiveInput'); <====== This expects a value
        const modifiedContent = $.html();
```

Any pointers on how to do this is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What if pass null as the second argument?

Comment: Does not work. I tried that.

Comment: What happens exactly when you use `null`? `directiveInput` is equivalent to `directiveInput=""` technically. What happens if you pass an empty string as the second argument?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add empty value to `attr` tag. e.g.

```
$('input').attr('directiveInput', '');
```